# Is it possible to set the Windows 10 time zone through Intune and if so, should we?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-intune

Using AutoPilot to provision Windows 10 v1803 devices, it only asks for the user's language and the user's credentials. After a few minutes waiting at the AutoPilot status page, the user is logged on and the time is set to the default time zone, which is incorrect for us.

Is there a "better" way to configure the time zone, than giving the end user directions on how to change it themselves? It is not as if we would be teaching the user a valuable life skill, they will use often.

Comment: Do you have a means to set the region during install ? I recall that actually determines the timezone (vs setting the TZ directly).

Comment: It does ask the region, but "United States" is rather broad.

Comment: Doing it via the registry is an ugly hack but it ought to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick update on this you should be able to deploy a powershell script to users through intune to fix the timezone issue and the latest CU is suppose to resolve the time zone issue.
The powershell script to change time zone this should be deployed to users not computers:

```
Set-TimeZone -Name 'Central Standard Time'
Start-Service W32Time
Restart-Service W32Time
```

The CU that is suppose to resolve the timezone issue:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4340917/windows-10-update-kb4340917

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is not a good way to change the time zone with devices managed by intune. I work for a school district that did a Windows 10s pilot with Microsoft and that was one of the bigger issues we had with intune. Supposedly Microsoft is working on a way to set the timezone either with a provisioning package or the autopilot setup but I have not heard anymore on that.